# How to setValue/PatchValue multiple value in ngselect in reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ngselect

**[image: I am facing trouble on populating ng select value from database.]** I have ng select which consist of languages. a user can have multiple languages. on binding multiple selected value on ng select its showing empty tags. my code is below. **on edit i want to display saved languages tags on ng select but its showing empty tags someone please help. I am using reactive form**
**Image for reference is attached **

> HTML

```
 <ng-select class="w-100" [multiple]="true"   [hideSelected]="true" placeholder="Please Select Language"
            formControlName="language" [bindValue]="language.id"  [bindLabel]="language.name" 
            >
            <ng-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language.id">{{language.name}}</ng-option>
          </ng-select>
```

> Typescript

this.form.patchValue({  language: this.editData.teacherProfile.teacherProfile.language })

> Data is retrieving in this form
> "language": [
> {
> "_id": "5fb79cdd34ec021e64c2413e",
> "name": "English",
> "id": "5fb79cdd34ec021e64c2413e"
> },
> {
> "_id": "5fb7996034ec021e64c2412a",
> "name": "Arabic",
> "id": "5fb7996034ec021e64c2412a"
> }
> ],

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the value you are set to the field, is available in the value option of the fields

Suppose the value set to the options of the select dropdown is id like 2, 3, 4 then you need to set the same value so that the name will get visible there

In the above case, as you share the data with structure, you need to get the all id's into the one array-like

```
languageID = [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and patch it to the field directly

```
   this.form.patchvalue({ languageid: this.languageID })
```

Comment: This explanation helped

Answer (score 2):

ng-select is "feeded" with an array, but not with an array of object, else an array of "id",

I suppose you need to make something like:

```
myForm.get('language').setValue(
               language.map(x=>x.id)
)
```

See how we create an array with the property "id" only using map.

Comment: I do have question in regards to mat table and it seems you have expertise here  can you please help me to resolve this mat table issue?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65347251/how-to-show-split-header-in-the-material-table-having-nested-group-of-data-in-an